# Rendering Plone SchemaAddForm without main_template?

Tags: tinymce, plone

I'm attempting to write a Plone add-on that requires an "Add new" form. So far, I've managed to get this working very nicely using plone.directives.form.SchemaAddForm. I have the '@@create-snippet' view registered in configure.zcml, and it works perfectly when I view the page normally.

However, the ultimate goal of this project is to get this add form into a TinyMCE popup window. I've created a working TinyMCE plugin for another, irrelevant portion of the add-on, and gotten that working well. However, when I try to navigate to my "@@create-snippets" view in a tinyMCE window, I get:

LocationError: (Products.Five.metaclass.DirectoryResource2 object at 0x107162fd0, 'main_template')

My understanding of this issue is that, essentially, the SchemaAddForm class (or one of it's super classes, to be exact) wraps the form with the main Plone main_template when it renders the form. Since TinyMCE windows are their own, isolated little worlds, the template isn't available, and, therefore, cannot be rendered....or something like that? Please correct me if I'm way off.

What I really want to know, is if it's possible to set things up so only the form itself will render, without using the main_template? I would REALLY like to be able to take advantage of the schema-based forms (and their built-in validation), but still be able to keep everything within a TinyMCE window.

I've toyed around with creating my own ViewPageTemplateFile() template, and getting the form to render (somehow?) within it, but frankly, I have no idea how....or if that's even possible.

Please feel free to ask for more information if there's something I've omitted. I'm kinda new to this type of Plone development.

The code generating the form:

```
from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView
from uwosh.snippets.snippet import SnippetManager
from plone.directives.form import SchemaAddForm
import zope.interface
from plone.autoform.form import AutoExtensibleForm
import zope.schema
from plone.directives import form
import z3c
from Products.statusmessages.interfaces import IStatusMessage

_ = zope.i18nmessageid.MessageFactory(u'uwosh.snippets')


class ISnippet(form.Schema):
    title = zope.schema.TextLine(
                                 title=u'Title',
                                 description=u'The title to associate with the snippet.',
                                 required=True)

    description = zope.schema.TextLine(
                                 title=u'Description',
                                 description=u'A short explanation of the snippet.',
                                 required=True)

    body = zope.schema.Text(
                                 title=u'Body',
                                 description=u'The actual content to be rendered on the page.',
                                 required=True)

class SnippetForm(SchemaAddForm):

    schema = ISnippet

    @z3c.form.button.buttonAndHandler(_('Save'), name='save')
    def handleAdd(self, action):
        data, errors = self.extractData()
        if errors:
            self.status = self.formErrorsMessage
            return
        obj = self.createAndAdd(data)
        if obj is not None:
            # mark only as finished if we get the new object
            self._finishedAdd = True            
            IStatusMessage(self.request).addStatusMessage(_(u"Snippet saved"), "info")

    @z3c.form.button.buttonAndHandler(_(u'Cancel'), name='cancel')
    def handleCancel(self, action):
        IStatusMessage(self.request).addStatusMessage(_(u"Add New Snippet operation cancelled"), "info")
        self.request.response.redirect(self.nextURL())


    def create(self, data):
        sm = SnippetManager()

        #TODO:
        #Include support for different folders from this form.
        snippet = sm.createSnippet(data['title'], None ,data)


        return snippet

    def add(self, object):
        #Since, for now, snippets are based upon ATDocuments, their creation is fairly staight-forward.
        #So, we don't really need separate Add/Create steps.
        return

    def nextURL(self):

        return self.context.absolute_url() + '/@@create-snippet'
```

Comment: Is the requirement unchangeable for you/are you forced to inject TinymCE? If not, please explain your usecase, there might be easier ways to do it. And make sure to have checked documentations for creating a TinyMCE-plugin (note the links you find about it here, if you want to be nice).

Comment: Using TinyMCE isn't strictly necessary, but that was the goal we wanted to shoot for. The "ideal" outcome would be that the entire add-on would exist from within the TinyMCE plugin, from the perspective of the user. I've gone over the TinyMCE-plugin documentation pretty heavily. My understanding is that my particular case is unconventional, and therefore there isn't much/any documentation addressing it. That being said, I'll post anything I find as I move forward.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just to know, if I got that right: A user is in editmode of a document writing stuff and then should also be able to trigger a popup to fill out the form?

Comment: Yes, that is what we're aiming for.